# Ceasar Cipher Encryption and Decryption with Java

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm use Ceaser’s cipher (shifting the alphabet by a shift pattern) with the shift pattern of two and then encrypt a sentence to print it on screen. Then I'm trying to store the encrypted message in a different string and decrypt it back to the original string. I've tried the following code below so far but I can't get it to decrypt back. Basically trying to encrypt and then decrypt in Ceasar's cipher, but so far I can only encrypt and not decrypt it back. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
public class Solution { //to keep track of index
  public static final String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  public static String encrypt(String message, int shiftKey) {
    message = message.toLowerCase();
    String cipherText = "";
    for (int ii = 0; ii < message.length(); ii++) {
      int charPosition = alpha.indexOf(message.charAt(ii));
      int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
      char replaceVal = alpha.charAt(keyVal);
      cipherText += replaceVal;
    }
    return cipherText;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = new String();
    int key = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter the String for Encryption:");
    message = sc.next();

    System.out.println("\n\nEnter Shift Key:");
    key = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\nEncrpyted msg:" + encrypt(message, key));
  } //main method ends
```

Comment: normally, the encrypt/decrypt would be: if you encrypt using a shift of 1, you decrypt by using a shift of -1

Comment: Please see [mcve] . You only posted a bit of code, and some vague explanations. But you didnt tell us what exactly you did, and where things go wrong, or what you actually want from us. And please pay attention to the formatting/indenting of your code!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so can you store the cryptogram in a String, then call your encrypt method with that string and -1 * key?

Comment: Not sure, how would I do that exactly?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypt with `shiftKey = 10` you need to decrypt with `shiftKey = 16`. So when you enter `-10` to reverse the process, you need to add `26` if it is negative.  Right before your `for(ii ..)` loop put this.

```
 shiftKey = shiftKey < 0 ? alpha.length()+shiftKey : shiftKey;
```

Says if `shiftKey` is less than `0`, add `alpha.length()` to it.  Otherwise keep it as is.